# using sudo in python script properly

Tags: python

so i was trying to make a script that will download and update all software i use, when installing,reinstalling system etc. so i have written this but it also run makepkg as sudo. How to run just chown as sudo?

```
import os
from os import chdir as cd
import subprocess
print('Enter admin username(not root):')
username = input()
def username():
    global username
print('Password to use sudo:')
psswd = input()
def psswd():
    global psswd
    os.system('cd ~/Dokumenty/github')
    os.system('git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay-git.git')
    os.system("sudo chown -R +username ./yay-git");
os.system('cd yay-git')
os.system('exit')
os.system('makepkg -si')
```

Comment: What's the point of the `username()` function whose body is just a `global` statement?

Comment: Don't use the same name `psswd` for a variable and function.

Comment: Each `os.system()` call starts a new shell, it doesn't continue the previous shell.

Comment: You never call either of the functions that you define

Comment: What is `chown -R +username ./yay-git` supposed to do? The variable won't be substituted into the string.

Comment: Why are you doing this with Python? It seems like what you really want is a shell script.

Comment: try to use sudo -k in the command you want to execute as sudo